# Playback using saved session cookies

Tags: security, cookies, session-cookies

I did a small sample test and found that almost all web sites I tested suffer from the vulnerability where I can access restricted pages (ie pages that require logging in) even after I have logged out from the browser if I save the cookies while I am still logged on.

The test was fairly simple. I just replayed a web request in Fiddler **after** I had logged out from the browser. For example, with outlook.com, after logging out, I could replay the page that shows the address book and still get my contacts' email addresses.

May I know what the industry standard is regarding this as I have one customer who insists on fixing this vulnerability but not wanting to increase the hardware specs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an industry standard, but there are best practices.  And the best practice is to clean the cookies, and cookie management.

You shouldn't have to worry about hardware on this either.  It's a simple lookup to see if a value is valid.  If it isn't, then the session state shouldn't get resurrected.

Again, I would use HttpOnly and a secure flag on the cookie.  That way, it will limit replay attacks more.  And when it comes to resurrecting sessions, make sure that session files are destroyed on the server, not just abandoned.

Abandoned sessions mean they can potentially be resurrected.

Hardware will generally not be an issue with this problem.  If it is, then look at your solution, as there might be a better way.